# Script to parse .xml files and list tags

Tags: xml, list, parsing

I need a script to go through a directory recursively and parse every `.xml` files and list tags by order of most frequent to less frequent and tell how many times each tag appears in order to make a statistic of wich are the most used ones.

I was thinking Perl but if you think there is a better way please let me know.

I was able to find a perl script that counts words in a document

```
sub by_count {
   $count{$b} <=> $count{$a};
}

open(INPUT, "<[Content_Types].xml");
open(OUTPUT, ">output");
$bucket = "";

while(<INPUT>){
   @words = split(/\s+/);
   foreach $word (@words){
            if($word=~/($bucket)/io){

      print OUTPUT "$word\n";
      $count{$1}++;}

   }
}
foreach $word (sort by_count keys %count) {

   print OUTPUT "$word occurs $count{$word} times\n";

}

close INPUT;
close OUTPUT;
```

But i'm having trouble defining the $bucket variable, this script was intendend to define bucket like

```
$bucket = "monkey | tree | banana"
```

and the output would be like

```
word monkey occurs 4 times
word monkey occurs 3 times
word monkey occurs 1 times
```

In my case i'd have to use wildcards so it will parse everything in between <> like

```
$bucket = <"<*"."*>">;
```

but this creates an output file containing all xml code and counts every "<" and ">" added toguether and outputs

```
occurs 50 times
```

I need something that does the following:

Example .xml document:

```
<tag1 This is tag1 />
<tag1 This is tag1 />
<tag2 This is tag2 />
<tag2 This is tag2 />
<tag1 This is tag1 />
<tag2 This is tag2 />
<tag3 This is tag3 />
```

Output:

```
<tag1 This is tag1 /> appears 2 times 
<tag2 This is tag2 /> appears 3 times 
<tag3 This is tag3 /> appears 1 time
```

---

**SOLVED:**

```
#usr/bin/perl

sub by_count {
   $count{$b} <=> $count{$a}; 
}

open(INPUT, "</file.xml"); #xml file
open(OUTPUT, ">outputfile"); #Create an output file
$bucket = qw/./;


while(<INPUT>){
   @words = split(/\</); #Whenever reaches a '<' breaks the string

   foreach $word (@words){
            if($word=~/($bucket*>)/io){

      #print OUTPUT "$word";
      #print OUTPUT "\n\n";
      $count{$1}++;}

   }
}
foreach $word (sort by_count keys %count) {

   print OUTPUT "<$word occurs $count{$word} times\n\n";

}

close INPUT;
close OUTPUT;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<Default Extension="xlsx" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"/> occurs 1 times

<Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png"/> occurs 1 times

<Override PartName="/word/theme/theme1.xml" ContentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml"/> occurs 1 times
```

Thank you all for your help, it was really helpful, an to cfrenz for the code he put on his blog wich i editted

http://perlgems.blogspot.pt/2012/05/normal-0-false-false-false-en-us-x-none_2673.html

Comment: I'd use Perl for this, but that's mostly personal preference and I'm not going to write the entire program for you. There are no shortage of XML libraries on CPAN. What have you tried? What problems have you encountered?

Comment: I'm actually new to perl and i'm a little lost. I'm still trying to figure out the logic to do this and only then i'll be able to transform it in code. I've already did one to list by file names and count repetitions but i assigned what names too look for. In here i don't know how many different tags i will find so i need to find a way to print each tag encountered, say everything between a '<' and a '/>' and print it with the occurrencies of that tag

Comment: I'm thinking of using the glob function. What do you think?

Comment: XML is not a regular language, you cannot parse it using regular expressions - at least without special knowledge on limits of structures in the files. If you want to use perl, use some XML SAX library, add a listener on opening tags and increment a counter in a hash on its name each time this listener gets called.

Comment: Yes but i thought i could parse it like regular text, filtering everything in between '<' '>' won't that work?

Comment: The example you provided is no XML.

Answer (score 3):

Just to throw in an example in a language made for querying XML files, XQuery:

```
for $element in //*
let $name := $element/local-name()
group by $name
order by count($element) descending
return concat($name, ": ", count($element))
```

How to apply this to multiple XML documents depends on the query processor you're using, depending on your needs you could either do it within XQuery or just call the script for every file using find or whatever.

---

To execute you need an XQuery processor, for this example I will propose the open source software [BaseX](http://www.basex.org); you will be able to use all other XQuery engines, too. Make sure to install it so you have the command line wrappers, too; either by downloading and installing or using the "basex" packages in Debian and Ubuntu.

Store the script above in a file, here `test.xq`, and call use `find` to call it for every XML file in the current folder:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec basex -i {} test.xq \;
```

It will print the stats for each file.

Comment: Thanks Jens Erat but how do i run that script?

Comment: Extended my answer with a small example. I bet Perl will not be able to do that in 6 reasonable splitted lines of code when correctly parsing XML.

Comment: Should i replace anything in the test.xq script?

Comment: I installed baseX using sudo apt-get install basex in a ubuntu fork and it installed. But when i run the find . -name "*.xml" -exec basex -i {} test.xq \; command i got an error: [warning] /usr/bin/basex: Unable to locate /usr/share/java/tagsoup.jar in /usr/share/java

Comment: Don't know why it wants to use tagsoup without being installed. Easiest way would be to install the recommended package `libtagsoup-java`.

Comment: Thanks again Jens i got it working what i really need is the xml tags between < and />

Comment: This returns the tag names, like the other answer does. What do you really need? Please edit your question with a small example document and expected output.

Answer (score 2):

Oneliner using xml2:

```
find . -type f -name '*.xml' -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -n 1 sh -c 'xml2 < "$0"' | \
    grep -v '/@' | cut -d=  -f 1 | uniq | grep -o '[^/]\+$' | \
    sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Example output:

```
  48376 id
  16125 username
  16125 title
  16125 timestamp
  16125 sha1
  16125 ns
  16106 text
  14711 page
  10436 comment
   8032 minor
   4978 data
   4977 track
   4977 timecode
   4455 BlockGroup
   2262 ReferenceBlock
   1414 sitename
   1414 namespace
   1414 generator
   1414 case
   1414 base
    385 SimpleBlock
    142 discardable
    137 Timecode
    130 Cluster
    126 keyframe
     40 !
     38 name
     28 TrackType
...
```

**Update:**

Variant that "extracts everything between < and >", yet still using xml2 to handle XML correctly:

```
find . -type f -name '*.xml' -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 sh -c 'xml2 < "$0"' | sed 's!^\([^@=]*\)=.*!\1=!'  | 2xml | sed 's!>!>\n!g' | grep -v '^</' | sed 's!^<!!; s!/\?>!!;' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Example output:

```
   4986 id
   1662 username
   1662 title
   1662 timestamp
   1662 sha1
   1662 revision
   1662 page
   1662 ns
   1662 contributor
   1303 comment
    631 minor
    170 text xml:space="preserve" bytes="72"
     84 sitename
     84 siteinfo
     84 namespaces
     84 namespace key="9" case="first-letter"
     84 namespace key="8" case="first-letter"
     84 namespace key="7" case="first-letter"
     84 namespace key="6" case="first-letter"
     84 namespace key="5" case="first-letter"
...
```

**Update 2** Another attempt to understand what you want:

my input sample:

```
<q>
    <w tag="11"/>
    <w tag="22"/>
    <r/>
    <r/>
    <w tag="22"/>
    <w/>
    <w/>
    <w>ignore me
    </w>
    <r   />
    <ololo>
        <r />
        <!--
        <w tag="33"/>
        -->
    </ololo>
</q>
```

Script:

```
cat q.xml | xml2  | sed 's!^\([^@=]*\)=.*!\1=!' | grep -v '/!=' | 2xml | xmllint -format - | sed 's/^\s*//g' | grep -v '^</\|^$' | sed 's!/\?>$!/>!' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

Output:

```
  4 <r/>
  3 <w/>
  2 <w tag="22"/>
  1 <?xml version="1.0"?/>
  1 <w tag="11"/>
  1 <q/>
  1 <ololo/>
```

Is it something like what you want?

Comment: How am i supposed to run that? Sorry but i'm a newbie in linux and programming

Comment: Copy&Paste all four lines to the command line, like you did with my one.

Comment: Thanks it's working but is there anyway to list the entire line between < and />?

Comment: To see attributes you can remove `grep -v '/@'` chunk. Attributes hovewer will not be associated with their elements.

Comment: Updated solution with tying element to their attributes. Not tested thoroughly althogh. The script can be modified to exclude some attributes or to use only attributes names (not values).

Comment: Not working, Vi. Still outputting other values i don't even know what they are

Comment: Provide: 1. Sample input XML file, 2 Expected output, 3. Actual output you get with the script.

Comment: Still don't understand what should be done (without reading sample Perl code in question). Your sample output seems to be not very related to the input. And what is `**1**`? Provide simpler samples with shorter names and values (not tied to your problem domain), where you can see what should be counted. The question should be deducible from the sample input - sample output pair alone.

Comment: Issues with current sample: 1. `This is tag1` is not well-formed XML. Should be something like `This="is" a="tag1"` -- name-value pairs; 2. What should be consider about attributes? Their names or their values? 3. Omitted case like `<tag3 This is tag1 />`. Should it be just counted as tag3 or it should be a separate line?

Comment: Provided yet another script (this time the script process only one XML file although). Is it something like what you want?

Comment: This is an example of a tag in the original document:

<Default Extension="png" ContentType="image/png"/>

I want the program to parse the whole document output each individual tag and how many time that tag appears, so basicaly everything between '<' and '/>'

Comment: Is the final version of the script what you want? It preserves and counts elements with their tags. If not, provide your output for my sample input.

Comment: Is it just replace the file name and running it from the terminal? I got the error:

cm@cm-Satellite-L40:~/Desktop/teste/errortest$ [Content_Types].xml | xml2  | sed 's!^\([^@=]*\)=.*!\1=!' | grep -v '/!=' | clea2xml | xmllint -format - | sed 's/^\s*//g' | grep -v '^</\|^$' | sed 's!/\?>$!/>!' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
clea2xml: command not found
-:1: parser error : Document is empty

^
-:1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

^
[Content_Types].xml: command not found
error: Extra content at the end of the document
cm@cm-Satellite-L40:~/Desktop/teste/errortest$

Comment: You removed `cat` and tried to execute the xml file as if it were a program. Try `cat '[Content_Types].xml' | xml2 | .....`

Comment: I still have two errors
parser error : Document is empty
parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

Comment: Try increasingly executing pipelines with more and more chunks (starting from just `cat`, then `cat | xml2`, then `cat | xml2 | sed` and so on). At what step does it fail?

Answer (score 0):

For the input you provided (which is no valid XML)

```
<tag1 This is tag1 />
<tag1 This is tag1 />
<tag2 This is tag2 />
<tag2 This is tag2 />
<tag1 This is tag1 />
<tag2 This is tag2 />
<tag3 This is tag3 />
```

you can work with elementary unix tools:

```
$ sort <input.txt |uniq -c
```

This will return:

```
3 <tag1 This is tag1 />
3 <tag2 This is tag2 />
1 <tag3 This is tag3 />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jens Erat but i got it figured out

Comment: Any suggestion on how to make it recursive? I hava a directory with multiple subdirectories and inside all of those there is a [Content_Type].xml file. I want the script to parse every one of those files.

Comment: Start _learning_ about the tools you're using. You need to do the exactly same thing using `find` I proposed for two of these answers now, read `man find` on how to use it, if you showed effort yourself and don't succeed, feel free to ask a new question, probably better at [su] where this part is more suitable (it's not really about programming, but on using programs).

Comment: Ok i'll take your advice, thank you very much. Sorry for being such a noob but i just started an internship and i never programmed before.